# Disable Postcode / ZIP in Woocommerce checkout for African countries

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

Good day all, Please I'm trying to Disable Postcode / ZIP in Woocommerce checkout for African countries during Checkout.
Below is my code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'ssd_postcode_fields' );
function ssd_postcode_fields( $address_fields ) {
        $country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country(); 
            $africa_list_code= array('DZ', 'AO','BJ','BW','BF','BI','CM','CV','CF','TD','KM','CG','CD','DJ','EG','GQ','ER','ET','GA','GM','GH','GN','GW','CI','KE','LS','LR','LY','MG','MW','ML','MR','MU','MA','MZ','NA','NE','NG','RW','SN','SC','SL','SO','ZA','SS','SD','SZ','TZ','TG','TN','UG','ZM','ZW');

        if( in_array($country, $africa_list_code) ){
                $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;
        }
    return $address_fields;
}
```

Comment: If the user isn't logged in or doesn't have a saved billing country then your $country variable will return an empty string.  Are you trying to disabled the post code for all users regardless of if they are registered or not?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz I want to disable it for all African countries regardless if they are registered or not.

Comment: Then the code you are using above won't work because you are querying the customer's billing country which will always return an empty value.  You'd have to write some AJAX code that is triggered when you change the country to remove the country codes.